# Using SharedPreferences to save users score

Tags: java, android, list

I have 2 activities. In the first one i choose a level. In the second i play the game.In the second activity I answer questions and everytime I answer correctly I add one value to my arraylist. When the game ends a user goes back to level select activity and there he can see his score. For example: Level1: you answered 17 questions correctly. How can I achieve that? I tried using sharedpreferences but had no luck. It always shows 0. Im guessing its because it gets the value at the start of the game, when the list is empty. How to show the values after the game has ended when the list is filled?

This is the game activity in witch I create a list, store values in it and answer questions.:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Button mYes;
    Button mNo;
    TextView mQuestion;
    Button btnClosePopup;
    TextView mPopupText;




    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        final int[] count = {0}; // Global array.
        final int[] score = {0};
        //final int[] intArray = new int[3];
        mYes = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        mPopupText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.popupTekstas);
        btnClosePopup = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_close_popup);
        mNo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        mQuestion = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);



        //Creating questions. (Question, boolean, answer).
        final Question first = new Question("Do i understand this code?", true, "Only Jesus knows");
        final Question second = new Question("Why dont i understand this code?", false, "Im not Jesus");
        final Question third = new Question("Why I am not Jesus?", true, "2fat.");
        //Creating Lists for questions and boolean values.
        final ArrayList<Question> questions = new ArrayList<Question>();
        final ArrayList<Boolean> type = new ArrayList<Boolean>();

        final ArrayList<Integer> points = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("level1", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();

        editor.putInt("taskai", points.size());

        editor.commit();

        //mResult.setText("zdr");

        //Adding questions to the question list
        questions.add(first);
        questions.add(second);
        questions.add(third);



        // Adding boleans to the boolean list
        type.add(first.correctAnswer);
        type.add(second.correctAnswer);
        type.add(third.correctAnswer);

        //Show the first question on Activity start.
        mQuestion.setText(questions.get(0).question);


        // Open PopUp Window on true button click.
        mYes.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                initiatePopupWindow();
                if(type.get(count[0])){

                    ((TextView)pwindo.getContentView().findViewById(R.id.popupTekstasTiesaArNe)).setText("Correct!");
                } else {
                    ((TextView)pwindo.getContentView().findViewById(R.id.popupTekstasTiesaArNe)).setText("False!");
                }
               //Show the first answer on first button click.
                ((TextView)pwindo.getContentView().findViewById(R.id.popupTekstas)).setText(questions.get((count[0]) % questions.size()).answer);
        // When PopUp button closes open the next question with the if/else conditions.
            btnClosePopup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    //if the question is true show next question/ else close app
                    if (type.get(count[0])) {
                        points.add(1); // if the answer is correct add +1 to the list.
                        score[0]++;
                        if(questions.size()-1 == count[0]) // if you count[0] is init to 0
                        {

                            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                            builder.setTitle("WInner");
                            builder.setMessage("You won, play again?");
                            builder.setCancelable(false);
                            builder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes,
                                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                            // just close dialog
                                            dialog.cancel();
                                        }
                                    });
                            builder.setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no,
                                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                         finish();

                                        // mResult.setText("" + points.size());

                                        }
                                    });

                            // Create dialog from builder
                            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();

                            // Show dialog
                            alert.show();
                            count[0]=0;


                        }
                        else if(questions.size()-1 < count[0])
                            try {
                                throw new Exception("Invalid ");
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        else
                        count[0]++;

                        mQuestion.setText(questions.get(count[0]).question); // you dont need calculate the module anymore
                        pwindo.dismiss();
                    } else {
                        count[0]++;

                        mQuestion.setText(questions.get(count[0]).question); // you dont need calculate the module anymore
                        pwindo.dismiss();
                    }

                }
            });

            }
        });

        mNo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                initiatePopupWindow();
                if(!type.get(count[0])){

                    ((TextView)pwindo.getContentView().findViewById(R.id.popupTekstasTiesaArNe)).setText("Correct!");
                } else {
                        ((TextView)pwindo.getContentView().findViewById(R.id.popupTekstasTiesaArNe)).setText("False!");
                }
                ((TextView)pwindo.getContentView().findViewById(R.id.popupTekstas)).setText(questions.get((count[0]) % questions.size()).answer);

                btnClosePopup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        if (!type.get(count[0])) {
                            points.add(1); // if the answer is correct add +1 to the list.
                            score[0]++;
                            if(questions.size()-1 == count[0]) // if you count[0] is init to 0
                            {

                                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                                builder.setTitle("WInner")
                                        .setMessage("You won, play again?")
                                        .setCancelable(false)
                                        .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes,
                                                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                                        // just close dialog
                                                        dialog.cancel();
                                                    }
                                                })
                                        .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no,
                                                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                                        finish();
                                                        //mResult.setText("" + points.size());





                                                    }
                                                });

                                // Create dialog from builder
                                AlertDialog alert = builder.create();

                                // Show dialog
                                alert.show();
                                count[0]=0;

                                ((TextView)pwindo.getContentView().findViewById(R.id.popupTekstasTiesaArNe)).setText("Klaida!");
                            }
                            else if(questions.size()-1 < count[0])
                                try {
                                    throw new Exception("Invalid ");
                                } catch (Exception e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            else
                                count[0]++;

                            mQuestion.setText(questions.get(count[0]).question); // you dont need calculate the module anymore
                            pwindo.dismiss();
                        } else {
                            count[0]++;
                            mQuestion.setText(questions.get(count[0]).question); // you dont need calculate the module anymore
                            pwindo.dismiss();
                        }

                    }
                });


            }
        });
    }

    public PopupWindow pwindo;

    public void initiatePopupWindow() {
            try {
// We need to get the instance of the LayoutInflater
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) MainActivity.this
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.popup,
                    (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.popup_element));
            pwindo = new PopupWindow(layout, 500, 570, true);
            pwindo.showAtLocation(layout, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);

            btnClosePopup = (Button) layout.findViewById(R.id.btn_close_popup);
            btnClosePopup.setOnClickListener(cancel_button_click_listener);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public View.OnClickListener cancel_button_click_listener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            pwindo.dismiss();
        }
    };
```

In this activity I try to get the list values and show them:

```
public class LevelSelectActivity extends MainActivity {

    Button mLevel1;
     public TextView mResult;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_level_select);

        SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("level1", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        int result = sharedPref.getInt("taskai", 0);


        mLevel1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.level1);
        mResult = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.Resultas);
       // mResult.setText(players.size()-1 + "/" + 3);

        mResult.setText("" + result);

        mLevel1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent startGame = new Intent(LevelSelectActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(startGame);

            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: you can pass like an intent parameters in LevelSelectActivity like startGame.putExtras("key",value); both are strings only if you want to get in MainActivity then call getIntent().getStringExtra("key"),it will execute.

Comment: Save the score when the game ends. Also there is really no need to use an ArrayList. Just use an int and increment it everytime the player gets a point.

Comment: but will the score save that way?

Comment: @Longi how can I save the score?

Comment: you save the score when the activity starts not when you finish. Do it in onPause method for exmaple.

Comment: But that will save the score until the program runs. I need to save the score with sharedPreferences so the score would stay even if I close the app.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know for sure what's happening in your code, but I do know preferences aren't the best way to pass data.

You are better off using a [set results/ get results pattern](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html).

The first activity uses

```
startActivityForResult(intent, LEVEL_REQUEST);
```

It will also create a function to read back the data after it is done. That'll look something like:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // Check which request we're responding to
    if (requestCode == LEVEL_REQUEST) {
        // Make sure the request was successful
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

        }
    }
}
```

The activity sending the results will do this to publish the results:

```
Intent resultsIntent=new Intent();
//Set data in the intent, note this intent is returned to the original function in `onActivityResult`
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK,resultsIntent);
```

The second activity uses